# Respond.js with twitter bootstrap on ie8 and below

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, respond.js

i'm implementing a responsive website with twitter bootstrap but on iexplorer 8 and below can't use media queries.

I create a simple example for try respond.js but mediaqueries continue not working on iexplorer 7-8, here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<meta name="Description" content="Web description here" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the style.css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 38.75em) {
body {
    background: green;
}
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond#cdnx-domain-setup

CDN/X-Domain Setup

Respond.js works by requesting a pristine copy of your CSS via AJAX, so if you host your stylesheets on a CDN (or a subdomain), you'll need to upload a proxy page to enable cross-domain communication.

See cross-domain/example.html for a demo:

```
Upload cross-domain/respond-proxy.html to your external domain
Upload cross-domain/respond.proxy.gif to your origin domain
Reference the file(s) via <link /> element(s):

<!-- Respond.js proxy on external server -->
<link href="http://externalcdn.com/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy" />

<!-- Respond.js redirect location on local server -->
<link href="/path/to/respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect" />

<!-- Respond.js proxy script on local server -->
<script src="/path/to/respond.proxy.js"></script>
```

If you are having problems with the cross-domain setup, make sure respond-proxy.html does not have a query string appended to it.

Note: HUGE thanks to @doctyper for the contributions in the cross-domain proxy!

Comment: Thanks Craig.  This is directly from the docs but it doesn't really resolve the problem.  You can't upload the HTML file to Bootstrap's CDN, so do you need to simply ditch the CDN?

Comment: Simon, to be honest, I haven't spent the time to solve that issue yet.  I know it's possible.  In the interim I have just been resorting to using the local CSS for Bootstrap and CDN for everything else I can that doesn't need to get adjusted by respond.js.  If you find the answer, please post!  =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `<script src="./js/respond.min.js"></script>` above the `</head>` tag.

Comment: Above </head> and immediately after the stylesheets

Comment: respond.js should work even if loaded at the bottom of the HTML document, you're just more likely to get a FOUC. I think the real issue is that respond.js won't pull in stylesheets from other domains (e.g. the Bootstrap CDN).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add any code related with `respond.js`, load `bootstrap.min.css` through CDN except for IE 8. For IE 8, use local static file.

```
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>                                                      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <![endif]-->                                                            
    <!--[if gt IE 8]>                                         
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{CDN Address}" />                                                      
    <![endif]-->                                              
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->                                        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{CDN Address}" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Tested on IE 8 ~ 11 and other webkit browsers.