# Bootstrap 3 issue with IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question has already been asked by somebody else,i tried out the suggestions there,but it didn't worked out. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

So here is my problem,I created a simple login page using Bootstrap 3,it works fine in all browsers except IE8,the whole page stretches to full width in IE8 .
Another problem is that,a scroll bar appears at the bottom of the page in ALL browsers.
Screenshot of scrollbar issue http://i42.tinypic.com/sqgh82.png

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Bootstrap 3</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<style>
body{
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<div class="row">

<div id="login_panel_alerts" class="col-lg-4 center">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">Something went wrong!<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>
    <div class="alert alert-success">Success!</div>
</div>

    <div id="login_panel" class="col-lg-3 center modal-content">

    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-inline" placeholder="Enter username">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Forgot password?</button>
        </div>


    </fieldset>
    </form>

    </div><!--login_panel-->

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What all styles are there in style.css? Create a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gpKLz/

.center class is used to center an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
body
{
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    overflow-x:  hidden;
}
.center
{
    float: none; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Try this.

Comment: overflow-x:  hidden; <--- This helps in hiding the scrollbar,but will that cause any problem to any other elements?

Comment: It will not create any problem.

Comment: That solved the scrollbar issue,still waiting for a solution for IE8 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving relative widths instead of absolute ones in your css for the scrollbar issue?

Here's a good [article](http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/fixedvsrelative.shtml) on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you should try swapping out your classes in lower versions

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".col-lg-3).addClass("col-md-3").addClass("col-xs-3");
    $(".col-lg-4).addClass("col-md-4").addClass("col-xs-4");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

I did something similar to this but I changed from col-md-10 to col-md-9.  The way I understand it is as the screen shrinks past a certain pixel width (I believe @media contains this value) col-lg-4 goes down to col-md-8 then to col-xs-12, buut if you specify what you want the width of this to be in relation to the screen as it gets smaller.  You should see about the same look for your elements.