# Newbie Questions About HTML5 Boilerplate and Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, workflow, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5boilerplate

I started to use B[ootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) recently and I was thinking to set myself a workflow. To make my work faster I want to use [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/). I've found out that I can get a custom build of H5BP which comes with Bootstrap. This is kinda cool but I have a few questions about it:

1. There isn't any license file in the file I downloaded. Not for Bootstrap, not for Normalzr, not even for H5BP itself. Considering I'm gonna use them in a commercial project, is this appropriate?
2. Can I delete local Bootstrap files in  H5BP and replace them with CDN?
3. Is there something you would recommend to read or get familiar with before I start using them? (Could even be about setting a workflow).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it a bad question or a bad time?

Answer (score 1):

1. i found this license https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.3.0/LICENSE.md (MIT license) more about the license of Bootstrap (Apache 2 license ) you will find here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#license-faqs. You can use both in commercial project without any problem
2. Why not? jQuery and Modernizr also load from CDN. Keep in mind jQuery and Modernizr have a local fallback. You will have such a fallback for Bootstrap too maybe. Also see: [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3/17957495)
3. Read the [docs of Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), [HTML5 Boilerplate documentation](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.3.0/doc/TOC.md), etc. To answer question about your workflow be more specific. How do you use the HTML5 Boilerplate? Build every site from from scratch? Do you use a temaplate engine or cms? etc.