# Bootstrap 3.0 and IE 8 conflict

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a local design which is running on Bootstrap 3 and working well in all browsers except IE 8 and below.

I have tried including respond.js and html5shiv.js, though I couldn't succeed.

Comment: Please clarify the question, detail the problem, include source or possibly a JSFiddle (Fork this one here: http://jsfiddle.net/SjfzQ/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

Use this before clossing the  tag. Only rpoblem it does not work localy it must work on server that you can check, it does not wotk from file://

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```