# col-*-* will not work

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a face lift for company site. Its running IE8 and I am using a bootstrap css3 file. From what I've read this should work fine on IE8. I want to use col.md.3 and make 4 columns for a variety of data. I wrote this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <h3></h3>
           <p></p>
      etc...
    </div>
 </div>
```

But when it is saved - no columns. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check bootstrap support on IE8, [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support)

Remember puts inside head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Checks these threads too. [Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966522/wrapping-columns-in-ie8-using-bootstrap-3-and-respond-js) [Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802163/column-are-full-width-in-ie-8-css-bootstrap)