# Bootstrap 3 incompatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are using Bootstrap 3, but it doesn't work fine in Internet Explorer 8. When I open the page with IE8 it doesn't show nothing. All the page is white. We load respond.min.js when the is IE8 or 7, and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea? We tried too with css3-mediaqueries.js but nothing.

Comment: do you have it up somewhere we can look at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Sandra, we need more info.  Are you loading in the browser directly from your local system, or from a server? That makes a difference if you're using "respond.js" (which you should be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is, because it lacks explanation. Most problems can be solved with below Javascript includes

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="/assets/plugins-js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/plugins-js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a BS3 based site that required support for IE8 and later.  The head of your HTML structure should look something like what I have below. Note that "site.css" and "site.js" are your site-specific CSS and JavaScript library files.  Tested in IE8, Firefox and Chrome:

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />

<title>PAGE TITLE HERE</title>

<!-- Load Style Sheet(s) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/site.css" />

<!-- Load JavaScript(s) -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```