# Bootstrap .container not centered in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason, the .container element doesn't get centered in IE8. Here is the minimal code to demonstrate the problem I am encountering :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Title</title>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head><body>
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Online demo: http://tinyurl.com/ndn64tz

Comment: The demo link looks great at my side on IE8.

Comment: On my IE8 browser, the text "Test" is all on the left of the viewport.

Comment: Try the answer I have posted.. Should work.. Set the desired height..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is the problem, it appears well when I try it on my machine (IE11 with user agent changed)..
This trick should work.. (Override Container

```
.container{
  width:1020px; //or your desired width
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Make appropriate changes if needed.

**Alternative answer :**

Include this library after all the stylesheets are referred..

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

This will enable CSS3 Media Queries in old browsers.

and add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Source of alternative answer : [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 2):

do not forget to read bootstrap doc
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers

also use this tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
```

OR

```
<!--[if IE 8]><center><![endif]-->
 <section id="first" class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <!--[if IE 8]></center><![endif]-->
    <div class="col-lg-12">Helo World</div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Just add **center** tag