# Twitter Bootstrap and respond.js too responsive in IE8

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter, responsive-design

I'm having some issues with testing Twitter Bootstrap v3 in IE8. The problem seems to be the layout goes completely responsive in IE8 instead of showing the desktop version on the desktop using Windows 7.

This is the code in my head:

```
    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../docs-assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I see one of their examples works just fine, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respond.js only works with local CSS files unless additional steps are taken. I would recommend serving your 'bootstrap.css' file locally as a simple fix.

More information can be found at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers

Comment: I have added bootstrap.css locally 
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> but it is still going completely mobile first in IE8. Any other ideas?

Comment: Apologies on the late reply, is the website on an accessible test server?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I think that is the issue. I didn't realize you can't use the CDN.

I just found this thread as well that goes over several things:
[IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

I'll go through and I'm sure that and some combination of these items should do the trick.