# Media Query Site Issue with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I currently have a site that I inhereted the code and it appears it is not loading media queries properly for IE8. The respond.js script is loading properly, so media queries should be working. Any ideas on what I might be missing here?

The site is: http://ppcode.wpengine.com

Comment: I did have this problem and to me this link fixed it: http://cssmatter.com/blog/ie7-and-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query/ I hope that it works to you.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17957495/1763929).

Comment: @Vucko Yep that did it. We were using a CDN on the site, so that was causing the stylesheets to be pulled in from an external domain. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This article answers the question: [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3/17957495#17957495). We were using CDN to pull in assets and that caused the CSS to be pulled from an external domain, which broke respond.js.