# Bootstrap 3 Not Working in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html5shiv, respond.js

I cannot get Bootstrap 3 working on my client's site in IE8. I have scoured the web for hours reading tons of forums threads and doing all the suggestions but it is still not working. I have included `respond.js` and `html5shiv.js` and verified that they are being loaded properly. The site is http://www.drollyankees.com/ and here is what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bird Feeders &amp; Accessories | Droll Yankees</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=3.8' type='text/css' media='all' />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- blah blah blah -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.8'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read the docs: Respond.js and cross-domain CSS

Using Respond.js with CSS hosted on a different (sub)domain (for example, on a CDN) requires some additional setup. See the Respond.js docs for details. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers -- which means you have to host the css locally and link to it relatively.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

To something like this (using whatever is the relative path for your site):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="/path/to/your/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/your/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why can't you continue to use the CDN?

Comment: You can use a CDN, but you'll have to do some additional setup, as specified in the Respond README: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/README.md#cdnx-domain-setup

But it's simpler just to include it locally, via relative path.