# Custom wordpress theme with Bootstrap IE 8 error

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I've been stuck on this issue for a very long time and I would like to get some help from people out there who smarter than me.

I began building a custom wordpress theme with the frameworks of bootstrap 3.0. I uploaded the site onto a web server and the website isn't working on IE 8 properly. The layout is all jumbled up (here is the website http://www.plummedia.com.au/).

If you look at my code I have Html5shiv.js , respond.js and css3mediaquieries.js in my header.

I tried going through these steps but it has been unsuccessful. http://davekiss.com/ie8-respond-js-and-wordpress/

Please help thank you!

Comment: Already asked here: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173290/bootstrap-3-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: kirilloid I already have tried that. still not working :^/

Comment: You use jquery 2.0.1 version, it is not support for IE8, use jquery 1.* version