# Web page shows as mobile view on Internet Explorer 8 and 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a webpage which is responsive with bootstrap and for some reason in IE 8 and 9 it shows as it shows on mobile (small screen).

You can see a sample on http://www.my-cloud.gr/symvoulidis/login.aspx

There are still many users with Windows XP who they cannot upgrade to the latest version IE11 which is working fine with it.

Do you have any idea what to do to show it in normal view?

Comment: The website seems to run well in IE 9, you could [check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzfBI.jpg). In IE 8 it shows different. You should try to include `html5shiv.js` and `respond.min.js` to make bootstrap work in IE 8. For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173290/bootstrap-3-not-working-in-ie8).

Comment: I am already did that if you see the code. And now suddenly find that even in IE11 is making the same thing.[link](https://paste.pics/42e7b52f9ad10c7aee8d65b94cc5ed36)

Comment: That's because you use `<meta>` tag with `content="IE=8"`, then the website will run in IE 8 mode by default. Try to use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`. And I can't see where you used `respond.js`, I can [only find `html5shiv.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yoby.png). Besides, you should check if the website not work in actual IE 8 or a later version of IE running in IE8 Compatibility Mode. Bootstrap doesn't support IE's Compatibility Modes, you could check [this thread](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10953).