# Rails 4 Bootstrap 3 Header Issue in IE 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have attached screenshots at the bottom. I have tried the following the tips from [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3) to no avail. I have tried adding respond.js, adding the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">` meta tag, and ensuring my markup is correct.  I have also ensured that both the html5shiv and respond.js are being loaded.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Relevant code**

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

  <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../vendor/assets/js/respond.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role='navigation'>
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Byrex</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">    
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

**Expected/All Other Browsers**

[image: Other Browsers]

**IE 8**

[image: IE 8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to use other sources of your scripts (and shiv 3.7):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Updating the scripts to use the CDN solved my issue.  My guess is updating the html5shiv from 3.6.1 to 3.7 fixed the issue.  IE 8 is a giant(and ugly) black box for me.

Comment: Great! I updated my answer. Yeah, supporting IE8 annoys me as well.

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 just blows, but that being said, it might help if you include calls for if the browser is IE8 --

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../vendor/assets/js/respond.js"></script>
```

I removed the "lt" because in recent experience, I had to do so to get IE8 to recognize it.  You can also throw in custom overrides between those tags to fix any other IE8 stupidity.

Comment: I'll give it a go but I can see the scripts being loaded in firebug so I don't think that's the issue. I'll edit the question to reflect that.