# IE 8 Bootstrap showing mobile navigation

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on a site http://www.clockinpoint.com which is using bootstrap 3 has the frontend framework but when you view the site in IE8 its showing as the mobile version how can one get around this?

Comment: Bootstrap is "mobile first", meaning the page is built and styled for mobile devices primarily, then using media queries it styles the page for larger screen sizes. IE8 doesn't support media queries which will mean your css will default to it's mobile first style. You would need to edit the CSS and switch your media queries to display the desktop styles as default.

Comment: How? In a seperate IE specific stylesheet? IS there no easier fix

Comment: You may move to Bootstrap 2.* while 3.* is not supporting old IEs

Comment: You would need an understanding of how the Bootstrap Grid system works, and how it displays the site via the media queries, I can't help you there as I don't have much experience with Bootstrap.

Respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) might be your best option if you aren't looking to write or re-write new stylesheets.

Answer (score 3):

I have tested this so many time in localhost.It will never work in localhost,Jut upload the same folder on your server and then check it will 100% work.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not have support for media queries. Which is an issue while develiping mobile first.

You basically need a seperate stylesheet for IE8 if you want to fix this. But since you're using preprocessors there's pretty easy to [compile](http://www.theguardian.com/info/developer-blog/2013/oct/14/mobile-first-responsive-ie8) IE8 specific styles.

Answer (score 0):

IE8, like the others have said, does not support Media Queries.

However, if you include [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), you can manipulate it and the `js` will start thinking it can read it and it will work.

An example of this is [Just Seal It](http://justsealit.co.uk), IE8 works fine in terms of responsiveness.

If not, you need to create a new stylesheet.

Comment: I have the Respond.js file included but still renders has mobile site

Comment: You need to also include jQuery in the header of the site.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


are all included within the <head> tags
<script src="/js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>

Comment: As long as your jQuery file loads first and then respond.js loads after it, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

By importing this file http://d.pr/f/l0Yp from http://www.initializr.com/ this has fixed my IE issues, all working great now

Answer (score 0):

Try using polyfills. See this [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Using the polyfills mentioned, you'd probably end up having code that looks like this:

```
<script src="/path/to/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ...

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="/path/to/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="/path/to/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This worked well for me.