# how to allow bootstrap3 classes to work with Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have included html5shiv.js and respond.js for IE8 only, still not being able to fetch bootstrap3 classes for IE8 as all the Divs are loading with 100% width.

Comment: did you read all of this: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful:

Internet Explorer 8 and Respond.js
Beware of the following caveats when using Respond.js in your development and production environments for Internet Explorer 8.

Respond.js and cross-domain CSS

Using Respond.js with CSS hosted on a different (sub)domain (for example, on a CDN) requires some additional setup. See the Respond.js docs for details.

(from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)