# bootstrap support for IE8 of basic navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

My understanding was that bootstrap 3.xx supported IE8. When you to [the bootstrap's navbar example page](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)  and switch to IE's document mode to version 8. The navigation bar displays as if it's displaying in a mobile device or small screen at all times. 
Here is an image [image: NavBar collapsing on IE8]

I had this problem with a page I started developing and found people suggesting making sure to use Doctype which i was or using the non-minified version of bootstrap css which i tried without changes, then i noticed the sample page was doing the same, so the main question really is 
is IE 8 just not supported anymore?

Comment: Are you including respond.js from your local files or from a CDN? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: In my code I have to use local files, the work is for an intranet website, I tested almost every suggestion in that question. I have the [if lt IE 9] block pointing to local copies of html5shiv and respond

Comment: Couple of extra tips here: http://www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9

Comment: only thing I hadnt done there was the extra bits for the style, which didn't do anything, thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: Document Mode IE8 on an newer version of IE is *known* to behave somewhat differently than *actual* IE8. Try testing with actual IE8.

Comment: Bootstrap v3 still officially supports IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using IE11?

[Even in IE8 mode, IE11 doesn't respect conditional comments.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13177)
In particular, this means that it **ignores** the conditional comment containing the HTML5 element and CSS media query polyfills that Bootstrap advises:

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```