# Why IE 8 detects website as mobile?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I really don't care about IE8, but the clients do. I realized the IE8 detects responsive website as mobile and load the incorrect CSS.

For instance: www.bootply.com/render/62603

Any body has the same issue?

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Probably a twitter bootstrap 'thing'.

Comment: I guess that is a problem with bootstrap itself, try to file a bug report on github.

Comment: @j08691 this is general question, and the link is ready made Bootstrap template, not my code, i wonder why it's happening just for my knowledge.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: IE8 doesn't support complex media queries. If the stylesheet is written assuming mobile first and querying for desktop, the 2nd half won't succeed. And, note that Bootstrap doesn't support IE8 without Respond.js. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9

Comment: Thank you guys, that helped me out to figure out the issue, i wonder why people gave negative to my post.

Comment: The reason for that is already given - the same reason you just expressed disagreement with.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that IE8 thinks that it's a mobile, it's that it just doesn't understand media queries.

To quote [Jonathan Lonowski in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914356/why-ie-8-detects-website-as-mobile#comment36826503_23914356):

> IE8 doesn't support complex media queries. If the stylesheet is written assuming mobile first and querying for desktop, the 2nd half won't succeed. And, note that Bootstrap doesn't support IE8 without Respond.js.

You can get respond.js [here](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

[Bootstrap get started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9)