# Navbar Collapse in Bootstrap 3 not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a website using Bootstrap 3. I followed every suggestion from this question - [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3). I have included respond.js and html5shiv.js files and everything is working fine except the navbar-collapse. Here's the navbar-collapse code:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation </span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="image.png" width="143" /></a>
 </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="nav-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><a>About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My solution to a similar IE8 issue: [Bootstrap IE 8 issue related to Navbar (collapsed like mobile version)](http://hands-on-coding.blogspot.in/2014/09/fixing-bootstrap-ie-8-issue-related-to.html)

**Possible Fix 1:**

Basically, you need to avoid using CDN for bootstrap.min.css.

To fix the issue, you need to download bootstrap.min.css and place it in a subdirectory of your application, something like below:

/css/bootstrap/3.2.0/bootstrap.min.css

Related change in code:

If you are using bootstrap.min.css from a CDN like given below,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

then, replace the above code with a local version of bootstrap.min.css like given below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap/3.2.0/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**Possible Fix 2:**

Similar IE8 issue can still occur if you are trying to run the html file stored on local machine. Running the html file from a web server will solve the issue. Detailed solution given in the above blog post.

Comment: Also, if you are using a CDN, Respond.js needs a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the problem comes from the part where we include or call the bootstrap components i.e various style-sheets java-scripts  files.As per my experience when we include more bootstrap files then needed it causes conflict.I myself have done this navbar yesterday and had problem.
The solutions might be:

```
 1.Don't include unnecessary files,brings conflict.
 2.always keep the jquery file above bootstrap.js file
 3.Use the latest version as far as it is reachable to you.
```

I have done the same thing yesterday.Here goes my complete Code:
It is done in ASP.NET using visual studio 10.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="nav.aspx.cs" Inherits="nav" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">toggle</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="">helo</a></li>
            <li><a href="">by</a></li>
            <li><a href="">hy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</form>
```