# Bootstrap 3 - Responsive mp4-video

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, video, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, mp4

I tried to find a good solution on the bootstrap site but I didn't get an answer to this yet. I think I can't be the only one struggling with this, but I couldn't find anything that helped me.

I'm trying to embed an mp4-video on my website. The problem is, that if I use an iframe-tag I can't use autoplay and loop. 
Because of that I would like to solve it with a video tag (or something else that supports autoplay and loop). After that I tried to make my video responsive with an object-tag but this didn't work. Even though I let it in my code (to show you) which you can see below:

```
<div align="center">
   <object class="embed-responsive-item">
     <video autoplay loop >
       <source src="file.mp4" />
     </video>
   </object>
 </div>
```

I hope anyone of you can help me fix this.

Comment: File a bug next time! This will now be [fixed in v3.2.1.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14687)

Comment: @cvrebert I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

It is to my understanding that you want to embed a video on your site that:

- Is responsive
- Allows both autoplay and loop
- Uses Bootstrap

This [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Schybo/beaze7Lc/4/) does just that. You have to place another embed class outside of the object/embed/iframe tag as per the the [instructions here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) - but you're also able to use a video tag instead of the object tag even though it's not specified.

```
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Tested on ie9 and safari. Both work perfectly so you have something else going on there. Regarding ie8 - it [doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video) the <video> tag, and there are also [problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3) with using Bootstrap3 in ie8 - specifically with media queries. Please read the link to get more information.

Comment: This covers the whole page and is responsive but i want small height & width. how do i do that??

Comment: @J4GD33P51NGH Just change the `max-height` and `max-width` of the parent div of the video. See an [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/0k3wLqvb/).

Answer (score 17):

Simply add class="img-responsive" to the video tag. I'm doing this on a current project, and it works. It doesn't need to be wrapped in anything.

```
<video class="img-responsive" src="file.mp4" autoplay loop/>
```

Comment: class "img-responsive" is used for images and not for videos

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

`<video src="file.mp4" controls style="max-width:100%; height:auto"></video>`

Answer (score 5):

using that code wil give you a responsive video player with full control

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="640" height="480" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Lw_e0vF1IB4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: using that code wil give you responsive video player with full controloers

Comment: the question was about embedding HTML5 mp4 video and not a youtube video

Comment: Can't hear the audio!!

Answer (score 0):

Tip for MULTIPLE VIDEOS on a page: I recently solved an issue with no mp4 playback in Chrome or Firefox (played fine in IE) in a page with 16 videos in modals (bootstrap 3) after discovering the frame rates of all the videos must be identical.  I had 6 videos at 25fps and 12 at 29.97fps...  after rendering all to 25fps versions, everything runs smooth across all browsers.