# How can I make vimeo videos responsive for html email?

Tags: html, css, email, templates, vimeo

I want my html email videos to be responsive. So what will be the procedure for that? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In your **HTML file** , make div and paste below code there...

```
   <object class="responsiv-video">
     <video autoplay >
       <source src="file_name.mp4" />
       <source src="file_name.3gp" />
     </video>
   </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is to my understanding that you want to embed a video on your site that:

Is responsive
Allows both autoplay and loop
Uses Bootstrap
This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Schybo/beaze7Lc/4/) Here should do just that. You have to place another embed class outside of the object/embed/iframe tag as per the the instructions here - but you're also able to use a video tag instead of the object tag even though it's not specified.

```
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</div>
```

[Responsive mp4-video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040136/bootstrap-3-responsive-mp4-video)