# Bootstrap 3 - Responsive mp3 audio

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, audio, responsive-design, mp3

I am trying to add an audio player to my website which should work on both mobile devices and desktops ( responsive ). I found this link wherein I am able to add mp4 files easily to my bootstrap project. 
[Bootstrap 3 - Responsive mp4-video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040136/bootstrap-3-responsive-mp4-video)
Is there a similar code in bootstrap to add responsive audio files ?

Comment: so dumb to downvote the question, it comes up as #1 result in Google for the term "embed audio file bootstrap" and the answer points to 2 helpful libraries smh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in Bootstrap itself, you'll have to use an external library such as these:

[Audiojs](https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/) or [Bootstrap3_player](https://github.com/iainhouston/bootstrap3_player)

Comment: Hi I tried using the https://github.com/iainhouston/bootstrap3_player and it worked !!..Thanks a lot .!!