# Bootstrap Video Background Not Responsive (Not Scaling)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm trying to use bootstrap to make my personal website with a video in the background. When I make the browser window smaller, the video, title placeholder, and buttons all do not scale (not responsive). I don't know what's wrong. Any help would be useful. Thanks so much!

Here's my HTML code:

```
  <div class = "header-container">
        <div class = "video-container">
                <video preload = "true" autoplay loop volume = "0"> 
                <source src = "videos/main.mp4" type = "video/mp4" >
                </video>
        </div>
        <h3 class="main"> 
            Title Placeholder 
                <div class="col-md-5 text-center col-sm-offset-3"> 
                        <a href="#services" class="btn btn-lg outline col-sm-offset-2">Services</a>
                        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-lg">About</a>
                        <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline">Contact</a>
                </div>
        </h3>
  </div>
```

Here's my CSS code:

```
.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you please create fiddle??

Comment: @SunilGehlot I'm not sure what creating fiddle means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 - Responsive mp4-video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040136/bootstrap-3-responsive-mp4-video)

Comment: @Harold Finch use that link : http://jsfiddle.net/ and create example and share updated link with us.

Comment: @SunilGehlot Not sure if I did it correctly. The video is local so I substituted it with one from the internet but the bootstrap buttons and title are not showing up http://jsfiddle.net/suLnu1r3/

Comment: @MadanBhandari I placed another embed class outside of the video tag, but the text and buttons are still not responsive. I've tried to enclose the text and buttons in an embed class but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

try to add in style

```
h3.main
{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
video
{
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Video is responsive, but text and buttons are not unfortunately

Comment: your text and button already in center and responsive what you want

Comment: Text and button are not responsive. This is what it looks like: http://imgur.com/a/yWWdl

Comment: edit on fiddle for text and button you wants because your video fiddle jsfiddle.net/suLnu1r3 is working

Answer (score 1):

Okay you are giving the `.video-container` a static height. Make it's height to `100%` . After that grab your `video` element and give it a `min-width` and `max-width` of `100%` . Yo might also need to add the `max-width` property to the `video` and set it to `100%`. You can also use `width` and `height` of `100%` rather than using `min-width` and `min-height`. See what works and create a fiddle.

```css
.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video { max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
```