# How to make video responsive but still watchable?

Tags: css, video

I made a video responsive in Bootstrap with the following code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
     <video src='#' width='640' height='360'>
</div>
```

The code works perfectly and correctly is responsive. Butt he video itself isn't centered and isn't showing me the entire video. Only a small part of it. It's kind of hard to explain. I've included two screenshots of the same video and time of the video but on different screen sizes.

How do I center the video and still keep my current responsiveness for the video?

[image]
[image]

Comment: so the below screen is a issue?

Comment: Have you try like this 
<video src='#' style="width:100%">

Comment: @chiragsolanki Yes to both questions :)

Comment: send here fiddle?

Comment: Go through Below link its may help
http://azmind.com/bootstrap-tutorial-modal-video/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RahulRB1997/9qpy4faw/1/)
Your `<div>` is bootstrap responsive, but you also need to make your video tag responsive, so the Video tag embedded will be:

```
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src=your_video_url type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</div>
```

You can remove `autoplay loop` in video tag, it'll prevent video from autoplay as soon as page is opened and removing loop will prevent the video from repeating itself over and over again (until paused).

Comment: Another post here references this same fix with a little more discussion and information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040136/bootstrap-3-responsive-mp4-video