# Video not responsive on screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my video to be responsive and scale size depending on the display size but its not working. I'm using bootstrap 3x

```
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <video class="embed-responsive-item" onloadstart="this.volume=0.05" width="1080" loop="true" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="assets/images/compilation1-HB.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
      </video>
      </div>   
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it's version 3 of Bootstrap? Can't you switch over to version 4?

Comment: I could make your code work like intended with no hassle: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/22a946f45384a887e3f97425e5372b3c There must be something else  that causes your issue. You have to post an example that shows the wrong behavior in order for us to help you

Comment: @yunzen how did you do that? is that bs3? Im using bs3 because its an old project and im only modifying it.

Comment: I only copied your code and used bootstrap 3.4.1 (edit this behind the cogwheel top left of CSS field)

Answer (score -1):

have you checked this post yet? [Bootstrap 3 - Responsive mp4-video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040136/bootstrap-3-responsive-mp4-video)

And i see in your code have an excess close div tag. May be that is the problem.

Comment: The div is okay. I just didnt copy the div above my mistake. And yes, I already checked the 3.x documentation still no luck

Comment: The accepted answer in that post is the same code as in the OP