# Bootstrap panel showing left aligned in IE-8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have used **Bootstrap panel** for creating login form.

But when i check my ui in IE-8 it looks left centered also the **glyphicon-icons** also not showing.
in other browser it looks perfect.

```
        <div class="message warning">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6>
     <div class="panel panel-default" >  
                    <div class="panel-heading" >
                        <span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-eye-open "></span> Login
                    </div>
         <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-4">Organisation Id</label>

                <div  class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7">
                    <div class="input-group">
                         <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" require placeholder="Organisation Number" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-4">Username</label>

                <div  class="col-xs-7">
                    <div class="input-group">
                         <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" require placeholder="Username" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4">Password</label>
                  <div  class="col-xs-7">
                    <div class="input-group">
                         <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" require placeholder="Password" >
                     </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="checkbox input-group">
                        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                      <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>  -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
     </div>
     </div> 
    </div>  
    </div>
```

i have attached image so you can easily identified problem.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: my problem is layout is not visible in center and icons were also not visible.

Comment: no, it's different issue , as because i have used bootsrap-panel componant. @Raptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution for this problem.
i have added some extra css code, and it's working in IE-8 also.

```
.center {
 float: none;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 center ">
```

Comment: Anyone encountering similar issues in future please see the initial comment by @Raptor and the linked question. Adding "center" class only fixed the typo in the code you supplied(line 2 - missing closing quotes). Correct ordering / use of your bootstrap.css, html5shiv.js and respond.js as well as location of these files (local vs cdn) will allow media queries in IE8 to _respond_ as you expect them.

Answer (score 0):

This *maybe* caused by the page being served from the local file system.

**Update**: There maybe other reasons such as cross-domain issues when requesting your bootstrap css and js files from a cdn. The link below details further caveats when using Respond.js in your development vs production environments for IE8.
Please note there was also some changes in v3.0.1 regarding the use of `box-sizing: border-box;` due to [IE8 lack of full support](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-box-sizing)

To solve this you need to view this over http, the responsive features will then appear as you expect in IE8 (Document Mode 8).

The [bootstrap docs explain](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs) this is due to a browser security rules relating to respond.js.

Comment: i tried in live server also it's not working yet.
Same look and feel.