# bootstrap is not working in internet explorer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have content side getting down in ie 8 but on chrome and firefox "Halaman Dashboard" position in the right side not in below sidebar. Thanks a lot.

I need help for this.

[image]

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? Bootstrap 3 dropped IE8 support. This looks to be your issue.

Comment: ok thanks. the version is Bootstrap v3.2.0. so should I change the version? what is the version? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't fully support html5 and media queries. You'll need to include this in your documents head:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```