# How can I determine the compatibility of the browser to Bootstrap with Modernizr?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compatibility, modernizr, browser-detection

I want to determine if a browser is compatible to the CSS framework [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). I want to show a note, if the given browser doesn't support it (e.g. Internet Exporer 8). I prefer the feature based detection with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com), but I don't know which aspects/features I have to test to guarantee the compatibility to Bootstrap.

I don't want to get Bootstrap running with IE8, I just want to test if the given browser supports all features that are necessary to run with Bootstrap 3. So [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3) will not help me.

Does anyone have an idea which features I have to test with Modernizr?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: In this link http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support the browser support is described. Why do you want to run your own tests? Your users will have older versions of Firefox / Chrome?

Comment: Yes, some of our users may use older versions of Firefox or Internet Exlorer. We don't want use things like Respond.js or other workarounds mentioned in the support page to get Bootstrap running on older browsers.

Comment: Furthermore we don't want to do browser detection by the user agent string because it is [unreliable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent#Notes).