# IE 8 with bootstrap media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see http://emailforusa.com/KarmaNew/

The bottom portion is appearing one below another instead of as 3 column.

I am conditionally using html5shiv.min.js and respond.min.js but could not figure it out why.

Also tried with Google's http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js and https://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js   but the problem is not solved.

Any help ?

Comment: Just to clarify - the problem is that the columns within the div ".advantages" align vertically instead of in a row when using IE8, correct?  In that case your question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Thank you very much !  I used local copy of bootstrap.min.css instead of maxcdn online copy and it worked.

Comment: No problem!  I've had the same problem myself.  Does your client require support for IE8?  Hopefully we won't have to deal with that browser version much longer.

Comment: Even though IE8 is outdated the client wants support for that too !