# How to make twitter bootstrap compatible with IE8?

Tags: html

I included below tags in my example, Still it's not working. col-md-* is taking full with of the div. col-md-* width is not showing at all in developer tool.

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="respond.min.js"></script>
           <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy">
        <![endif]-->
```

Comment: It's already solved from this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

For supporting @media queries in IE 8 and below, check out

https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

css3-mediaqueries.js by Wouter van der Graaf is a JavaScript library to make IE 5+, Firefox 1+ and Safari 2 transparently parse, test and apply CSS3 Media Queries. Firefox 3.5+, Opera 7+, Safari 3+ and Chrome already offer native support.

Reference:  [Twitter Bootstrap Responsive layout does not work in IE8 or lower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998877/twitter-bootstrap-responsive-layout-does-not-work-in-ie8-or-lower)

Also See : http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9

Update: There are plenty of questions/answers. You Just need to google it.

Comment: Give some usefull info otherthan googling it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look the size of your CSS, For IE up to IE9 the css file size is max 288kb. Maybe thats is a problem